# Анализатор обфусцированного JS кода

Tags: javascript, обфускация, статический-анализ

Существует ли в природе какой-нибудь анализатор статического
JavaScript кода, помогающий при разборе кода, прошедшего процедуру
обфускации?

Интересует анализ кода на наличие в нем и использование переменных,
утерявших свое первозданное имя.

Comment: Когда найдёте - попробуйте ему скормить http://www.jsfuck.com/

Comment: Хоть и не совсем по теме, но, @SanSYS, обфускатор интересный.
Его минус в том, что он каждую атомарную сущность интерпретирует предопределенно - https://github.com/aemkei/jsfuck/blob/master/jsfuck.js, что позволяет легко произвести деобфускацию.   

   
"Заурядные" JS-обфускаторы поступают проще: убивают оригинальные имена всего, что только можно. Итог: крайняя неудобочитаемость, особенно при больших массивах кода.

Comment: @0xFFh, так это и минификаторы обычные делают. Собственно, восстановить имя переменной вряд ли возможно

Comment: Восстановить - невозможно, конечно же.
Мне же нужно отследить их использование в минифицированном коде. Т.е найти в коде все места, где используется конкретная переменная.